# Jupyter Notebook not opening for Anaconda Navigator environment other than base

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an Anaconda environment named abc other than base environment. When I try to open a Jupyter Notebook using it, a window pops up in Google Chrome but the window remains empty. The Jupyter kernel keeps on running in the background though. How to fix this? (This problem does not occur with the base environment)

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the latest update to jupyter notebooks. The workaround is to downgrade back to the most recent working copy. I really wanted a way that used conda and not pip to downgrade, and I found an excellent solution. Anaconda keeps an archive of previous releases of the entire system (conda + jupyter + spyder + ...). You can find the archive here:

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

For me, the version that worked was the July 2019 release

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe

First you must uninstall Anaconda completely and then install the archived version.